# Critique my iterative binary search implementation in C

Tags: c, search

I implemented an iterative version of binary search and I'd like you to tell me what you would do differently and why. You're certainly welcome to critique style (e.g., header style, brackets, comments, etc.), but that's not really what I'm looking for.

I would like to know, for example, how you would handle large arrays that would cause
overflow errors with the indexes (I know, use a different data type, but would you only use one version with long int, unsigned lont int or whatever or would you have multiple and insert based on worst case). Do you see any edge cases that this implementation would fail? Could you make it faster? etc.

Thanks,

```
int binary_search_iterative(const int *arr,
                            const int arr_size,
                            const int target) 
{
    /*
    Performs iterative binary search on a sorted integer array. 
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    arr : int*
        A sorted integer array.
    
    arr_size : int
        Size of input array.
        
    target : int
        Value to look for in input array.
        
    Returns the index at which the value is found or -1.
    */
    
    int low = 0;
    int high = arr_size - 1;
    
    while (low <= high)
    {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        
        if (arr[mid] < target)      // Ignore left half
        {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else if (tab[mid] > target) // Ignore right half
        {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return mid;             // Found at mid
        }
    }
    
    // Not found -> return default value
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: There's a Stack Exchange for code reviews. You'll probably be told to go there.

This is the standard binary search.  Not much to be wrong except that the average computation can overflow if ints are 32 bits and the array has more than 2^31-1 elements.  Better to use  `low + (high - low) / 2;`

Comment: There is the case of repeated numbers, you'll get a non-specific index. A look at Java: when not found, they return the negative ones-complement of the insert position: `~mid` (more or less).

Comment: Yes +1 to @JoopEggen. Modifying the search so it always finds (for example) the first (or last) instance of equal elements without giving up O(log n) performance is an excellent exercise.

Comment: @Gene I see we have the same coding sadism. Tip: one can search for target-1 and target+1. I would do this in extra functions find_first/find_last. Using the insert-position variant of Java.

Comment: For feedback on working code please use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. This code you've written is nothing unique though, it's a common way of implementing binary search. You'll be able to find nearly identical code on the net and compare it with yours.

Comment: @Gene Duly noted, thank you.

Comment: @Lundin Duly noted. Thanks for the link. I wasn't going for anything special, it's just that binary search is notorious for being erroneously implemented (as is the case for my implementation) even according to Knuth.

Answer (score 1):

Logarithmic speed is fine. You have a typo `tab`/`arr`.

Use an other name for target: `search_key` or such.

Indexes are normally `size_t`, but `int` is fine, for the failure with `-1`.

Put `arr[mid]` in a variable; though the compiler will optimize it as such.

There is a possible speed improvement (which I would not use however). At every loop step, instead of halving the search range, you can do a weighted split.

Say you search 10, at low is 5, at high is 50000. Then you could take a logarithmic 500 as new mid, which saves about 8 iterations.

```
return ~low;
```

Would return the negative ones-complement of the insert position. When the search fails one can then easily insert the missing key.

There also exists the Dijkstra convention where the higher bound is exclusive, initially the size. This saves one subtraction for the new mid. So less code, and a tiny bit faster. Java uses that.

Comment: Is "search_key" more descriptive, more commonplace, or both? 

If my understanding is correct, the rationale behind storing `arr[mid]`  in a variable is to avoid accessing the array more than once and hence having to redo address arithmetic plus the data movement latency overhead?

I think that `return ~low` is a neat trick to convey two pieces of useful information. Thank you for that.

Much appreciated!

Comment: In binary search, *search_key* is common, playfully also *needle* (like in *needle in the hay stack*).

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation has a flaw:

- computing the mid point with `int mid = (low + high) / 2;` causes an arithmetic overflow if `low + high` exceeds `INT_MAX`. This will happen for large arrays with a length greater than `INT_MAX / 2`. It the searched value is toward the end of the array, computing `mid` will invoke undefined behavior, most likely produce a negative value, and dereferencing `arr[mid]` also invokes undefined behavior, possibly a segmentation fault. You should instead use this:

  ```
    int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
  ```
- also note the type in `tab[mid]` which should be `arr[mid]`.

There are also some minor considerations:

- using signed index values is necessary for your implementation because you might get a negative index value at `high = mid - 1;`, which will cause the loop to terminate without further issues.
- yet a signed type for `high` and `low` produces suboptimal code in `int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;` where right shifting must be adjusted for the potential case of negative values. As the value divided by `2` is always positive, you could avoid the adjustment with:

  ```
    int mid = low + ((high - low) >> 1);  // more efficient but less elegant
  ```
- the loop uses 2 comparisons in each iteration, reducing the span of the slice one element below half the current span and producing early exit when finding the target, yet it uses almost 50% too many comparisons when the element is not found and it does not return the minimal index when successful.  Note also that using 2 tests and a `return` statement prevents the compiler from generating branchless code. The first comparison is likely mispredicted, resulting in suboptimal runtimes on many CPUs.

A simpler loop avoids these shortcomings and allows for a more appropriate unsigned index type `size_t`:

```
int binary_search_iterative(const int *arr, int length, int target) 
{
    /*
    Performs iterative binary search on a sorted integer array. 
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    arr : int*
        A sorted integer array.
    
    length : int
        Number of elements of input array.
        
    target : int
        Value to look for in input array.
        
    Returns the index at which the value is found or -1.
    */
    
    size_t low = 0;
    size_t high = length;
    
    while (high - low > 1) {
        size_t mid = low + (high - low) / 2;  // uses a simple right shift
        
        //single test, produces branchless code
        if (arr[mid] <= target) {
            low = mid;
        } else {
            high = mid;
        }
    }
    if (low < high && arr[low] == target) {
        // return lowest index for a match
        return low;
    } else {
        // no match. low is the insertion point
        // could return ~low to indicate insertion point
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Charlie, but I don't see how the loop ends. Am I missing something?

Comment: @GodFearingEngineer: good point, the loop should stop when `high - low <= 1`. Answer updated.

Comment: Appreciated thank you!